# Uncaught in promise

Tags: javascript, java, rest

So I'm fairly new to JavaScript, i had a text document full of nouns, and thought what a good way to create an api with these nouns.

I read the file and added them to a List

```
public List<Noun> getData() throws IOException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new 
    File("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\nounlist.txt"));
    List<Noun> nouns = new ArrayList();
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        nouns.add(new Noun(sc.nextLine()));
    }
    return nouns;
}
```

This list i converted to Json with Gson:

```
@GET
@Path("/nouns/amount=all")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getAllNouns() throws IOException {      
    return Response.ok().entity(gson.toJson(nf.getData())).build();
}
```

I then started to create my frontend with js and tried to fetch the data, but ran into a problem saying uncaught in promise, type error, nouns.forEach is not a function

```js
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

const root = document.getElementById("root");
var url = "http://localhost:8084/CORSJavaJax-rs/api/noun/nouns/amount=all";
var tbody = document.getElementById("tbody");
var btn = document.getElementById("btnsend");

// fetch(url)
//   .then(res => res.json)
//   .then(nouns => {
//     var n = nouns.map(noun => {
//       return "<tr>" + "<td>" + noun.name + "</td>" + "</tr>";
//     });
//     tbody.innerHTML = n.join("");
//   });

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json)
    .then(nouns => {
      console.log(nouns);
      var n = nouns.forEach(noun => {
        return "<tr>" + "<td>" + noun.name + "</td>" + "</tr>";
      });
      tbody.innerHTML = n.join("");
    });
});
```

I tried both with map and forEach but with no succes, maybe im missing something or there is something I just dont understand about why i cannot map the data.

Comment: What is the print value of res.json if you console.log it?

Comment: What does the `console.log(nouns)` print? It looks like it is not an array. `forEach` is an array method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For what you want, the correct usage would be the `map` call, not the `forEach`. 
ForEach doesn't return a value, it just iterates on the collection.

The reason you are getting the `is not a function` error is most likely due to the missing function call on the `res.json`. It should be `res.json()`.

```
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(nouns => {
      console.log(nouns);
      var n = nouns.map(noun => {
        return "<tr>" + "<td>" + noun.name + "</td>" + "</tr>";
      });
      tbody.innerHTML = n.join("");
    });
});
```

Comment: oh wauw, I feel so stupid now, I always stare myself blind on stuff like this. Thanks for teaching me what is the correct usage is, and spotting my mistake!

Comment: I'm glad I could help! An unbiassed eye always helps on these 'staring yourself blind' situations :)

Comment: If it solved the issue, you should accept the answer to make sure SO history is updated

Comment: Great explanation